# remove css class from mutiple html elements

Tags: jquery, html, css

On html page I have multiple elements like,

```
<a class="myInput red  selected" selectable="">1</a>
<a class="myInput blue selected" selectable="">2</a>
```

point is that I could have many different myInput classes like red, blue, green, ...
Now I want on certain event to remove all `selected` classes from entire document.

I know that I should use `.removeClass("selected")` but I dont know how to apply on whole document to many elements

Comment: as long as they have that class it will be removed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$('.myInput.selected').removeClass('selected');
```

it only removes the `selected` css class from the `myinputs` and which has the class `selected`.

Answer (score 6):

You can find all `.selected` elements and remove the class like this:

```
$('.selected').removeClass('selected');
```

If there are multiple `.selected` elements found in the document jQuery will internally loop over all of them for you and change the class.

Answer (score 1):

You can use each loop like this as well :-

```
$('.selected').each(function(){
    $(this).removeClass("selected");
});
```

Comment: why loop each element when you  can just do `$('.selected').removeClass('selected');`?

Answer (score 1):

You can check with the code.

```
$(selector).removeAttr(attribute)
```

you can refer the below link too.

[Link](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_removeattr.asp)